# Bluetooth mouse disconnecting after I broke my keyboard's backlight controller

Tags: usb, keyboard-backlight

I have a Dell G15 5511, and because there is no driver/program to configure the keyboard backlight on Linux, I was creating my own using libusb.

I think I may have sent some faulty packets of data to it, because it has now become unresponsive. As soon as I turn on my laptop the backlight turns on and then slowly fades away (just as I configured it), but then it never turns on again. The controller doesn't even get listed on lsusb anymore.

That's not a big deal, the real problem is that now my bluetooth mouse keeps disconnecting after around three seconds of idle, and takes three more seconds to reconnect after I move it.

I've tried a fresh reinstall of my system to no avail, so it's definitely a hardware issue, but one I hope can be remedied with software configuration. The following lines are shown on dmesg when the mouse has been idle for a while and I move it:

```
[   37.578439] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[   37.692501] usb 3-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   37.909480] usb 3-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   38.132464] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[   38.246557] usb 3-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   38.469504] usb 3-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   38.578571] usb usb3-port7: attempt power cycle
[   38.958479] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[   38.958635] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   39.162741] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   39.370447] usb 3-7: device not accepting address 18, error -71
[   39.484498] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[   39.484655] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   39.690754] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
[   39.898482] usb 3-7: device not accepting address 19, error -71
[   39.898612] usb usb3-port7: unable to enumerate USB device
```

usb 3-7 is my (broken) backlight controller, that doesn't even show on lsusb anymore. How is it interfering with my mouse? Can I fix it? Or can I at least disable it so it stops messing with my mouse?

Here's the output of `lsusb -t`, in case it helps:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 20000M/x2
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
```